# Label on collection view header should be positioned above a specific cell

Tags: ios, calendar, position, uicollectionview

I want to have a label above a certain position in my collection view. Thereby the label can have a different size. For this I thought I use the supplementary views - namely the header. An example of this behavior can be seen in the iOS calendar:

[image: iOS calendar with the label]

The month name is either written in short form it the available space is scarce (last column) or written with the full name if you have more space. Also the month name starts with the first of a month.

What I can think of is to create a supplementary view, pass the content view size and calculates the distance from the side by multiplying the number of cells with the cell width. The cell width is calculated through the set collection view size and the data in the header defines the number of the cell. But what about orientation change and things like that? You can't use a cells header because the label can go over multiple cells.

How would you implement such a header?

**Solution:**

I used container each having the same width. On this container I added my labels. Now I can configure to either center the labels or position them at the beginning of the container. It now works for all orientations! Thanks [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar) for leading me to this idea!

Comment: I would think that the iOS calendar is implemented with a table view, not a collection view (I'm basing this on what I see on my iPhone running iOS 7). Do you need to use a collection view, or could you  use a table view?

Comment: @rdelmar: Currently, I build everything up with `UICollectionView`. I used this because it was called the better `UITableView`. Wouldn't the implementation of the header be similar? Because you would need to reposition the label.

Comment: If I were using a table view, I wouldn't use a header. I would make each month a section with no header view, and each of the cells would have 7 labels arranged horizontally. The first cell in each section would have the name of the month in the appropriate label, and the next row would have the number 1, start in that same label. Since the labels would be laid out with constraints in IB, you wouldn't have to do any calculations to position the month name, you would only need  logic to figure out which label, of the 7, would be the starting point for the month.

Comment: I could also place seven labels in the header. The question would be how do you set up the constraints then? If I look on the month names I observe the following: Short month names (consisting of 3 to 5 letters) are centered over the number. Longer month names start at beginning of the cell and extends over other cells as long as needed. How would you reproduce this behavior with your labels?

Comment: Now I tried adding 7 labels. Result: Not all labels were on its place. Labels which should be in the center, were on the right. If I changed orientation then labels which were before correct positioned are now centered. This was my constraint: `H:|-5-[label1][label2][label3][label4][label5][label6][label0]-5-|`. Giving all labels the same width, then the text doesn't overlap other labels. I could only use a short month name ...

Comment: Now I found a method: I used container each having the same width. On this container I added my labels. Now I can configure to either center the labels or position them at the beginning of the container. It now works for all orientations! Thanks for your idea!